# What's best way to make button inactive based on users previous choice?

Tags: java, android, button

Outline:

- Three buttons
- Based on user's selection, a button will become inactive
- Note user returns to this screen many times
- Upon selection, the button selected will be inactive or unavailable next time they visit the screen.
- If all three buttons have been selected (marked inactive), then they all become available again.

I'm unclear on how to even proceed with this. Any help or questions are welcome.

Here is my .XML, simple relative layout with the three buttons:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.android.cc09june.TeamA"
android:onClick="link">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Team A Offense Selection"
    android:id="@+id/TeamAOffSel"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/PandR"
    android:id="@+id/PandRA"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/TeamAOffSel"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:onClick="submitPANDR"
    android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/MandF"
    android:id="@+id/MandFA"
    android:layout_below="@+id/PandRA"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:onClick="submitMANDF" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/SandC"
    android:id="@+id/SandCA"
    android:layout_below="@+id/MandFA"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:onClick="submitSANDC" />
```

And here is my JAVA class for this XML and buttons:

```
public class TeamAOffense extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_team_aoffense);
}

// Button for Pick and Roll, where sharedpreferences assigns offense for use in another activity.
public void submitPANDR (View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ExchangeAToB.class);
    startActivity(intent);

    SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
    editor.putString("offense", "Pick and Roll");
    editor.apply();
}

// Button for Move and Flow, where sharedpreferences assigns offense for use in another activity.
public void submitMANDF (View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ExchangeAToB.class);
    startActivity(intent);

    SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
    editor.putString("offense", "Move and Flow");
    editor.apply();
}

// Button for Set and Called, where sharedpreferences assigns offense for use in another activity.
public void submitSANDC (View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ExchangeAToB.class);
    startActivity(intent);

    SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
    editor.putString("offense", "Set and Called");
    editor.apply();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_team_aoffense, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

Here is my UPDATED code, based on advice. Thank you!

```
public class TeamAOffense extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_team_aoffense);

    Button buttonPandr = (Button)findViewById(R.id.PandRA);
    Button buttonMandf = (Button)findViewById(R.id.MandFA);
    Button buttonSandc = (Button)findViewById(R.id.SandCA);

    SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", MODE_PRIVATE);

    // Calling string for comparison to enable/disable buttons, note these Strings have been set on a previous activity.
    String pandrASetting = pref.getString("pandrASetting", null);
    String mandfASetting = pref.getString("mandfASetting", null);
    String sandcASetting = pref.getString("sandcASetting", null);

    if(pandrASetting.equals("OFF") && mandfASetting.equals("OFF") && sandcASetting.equals("OFF")) {
        buttonPandr.setEnabled(true);
        buttonMandf.setEnabled(true);
        buttonSandc.setEnabled(true);

        pandrASetting = "ON";
        mandfASetting = "ON";
        sandcASetting = "ON";
    }

    if (pandrASetting.equals("OFF")) {
        buttonPandr.setEnabled(false);
    }

    if(mandfASetting.equals("OFF")) {
        buttonMandf.setEnabled(false);
    }

    if (sandcASetting.equals("OFF")) {
        buttonSandc.setEnabled(false);
    }
}

// Button for Pick and Roll, where sharedpreferences assigns offense for use in another activity.
public void submitPANDR (View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ExchangeAToB.class);
    startActivity(intent);

    SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
    editor.putString("offense", "Pick and Roll");
    editor.putString("pandrASetting", "OFF");
    editor.apply();
}

// Button for Move and Flow, where sharedpreferences assigns offense for use in another activity.
public void submitMANDF (View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ExchangeAToB.class);
    startActivity(intent);

    SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
    editor.putString("offense", "Move and Flow");
    editor.putString("mandfASetting", "OFF");
    editor.apply();
}

// Button for Set and Called, where sharedpreferences assigns offense for use in another activity.
public void submitSANDC (View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ExchangeAToB.class);
    startActivity(intent);

    SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
    editor.putString("offense", "Set and Called");
    editor.putString("sandcASetting", "OFF");
    editor.apply();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_team_aoffense, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this...

store the value of button say 1 with key button name in shared prefernces when the user clicked on it. and get the value in the onCreate method of activty, if value is 1, then disable the button.

```
    public class TeamAOffense extends ActionBarActivity {
    Button buttonPandr, buttonSandc, buttonMandf;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_team_aoffense);
        buttonPandr = (Button)findViewById(R.id.PandRA);
        buttonMandf = (Button)findViewById(R.id.MandFA);
        buttonSandc = (Button)findViewById(R.id.SandCA);

        SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", MODE_PRIVATE);
        String pandr = pref.getString("PANDR", "0");
        String mandf= pref.getString("MANDF", "0");
        String sandc = pref.getString("SANDC", "0");
        if(pandr.equals("1")){
          buttonPandr.setEnabled(false);
        }

        if(mandf.equals("1")){
          buttonMandf.setEnabled(false);
        }

        if(sandc.equals("1")){
          buttonSandc.setEnabled(false);
        }

// code to enable the three buttons again, if all the buttons are disabled.
        if(mandf.equals("1") && panfr.equals("1") && sandc.equals("1")){
           buttonSandc.setEnabled(true);
           buttonSandc.setEnabled(true);
           buttonSandc.setEnabled(true);
           SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
           editor.putString("MANDF", "0");
           editor.putString("PANDR", "0");
           editor.putString("SANDC", "0");
           editor.apply();
        }

    }

    // Button for Pick and Roll, where sharedpreferences assigns offense for use in another activity.
    public void submitPANDR (View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ExchangeAToB.class);
        startActivity(intent);

        SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
        editor.putString("offense", "Pick and Roll");
        editor.putString("PANDR", "1");
        editor.apply();
    }

    // Button for Move and Flow, where sharedpreferences assigns offense for use in another activity.
    public void submitMANDF (View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ExchangeAToB.class);
        startActivity(intent);

        SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
        editor.putString("offense", "Move and Flow");
        editor.putString("MANDF", "1");
        editor.apply();
    }

    // Button for Set and Called, where sharedpreferences assigns offense for use in another activity.
    public void submitSANDC (View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ExchangeAToB.class);
        startActivity(intent);

        SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
        editor.putString("offense", "Set and Called");
        editor.putString("SANDC", "1");
        editor.apply();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_team_aoffense, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Comment: But how would I also make them active again - once all three buttons have been chosen, I want to allow them all to be enabled again.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I used your code, with some minor tweaks,